# Open xdg-open does nothing in Chrome on KDE store

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, kde

While installing sweet.tar.xz through chrome, a pop up of open xdg-open not working. when I click on the open xdg-open tab nothing happens.

[image: Xdg open dialog picture]

Answer (score 1):

[`xdg-open`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) is a tool which opens file in the user's preferred application. The KDE Store install things Pling Store or OCS URL. Under everything in KDE store, a note is written

> *Needs [pling-store](https://www.pling.com/p/1175480/) or [ocs-url](https://www.pling.com/p/1136805/) to install things

It is expecting xdg-open to open either of them. But it seems that you have none installed.

You can install OCS URL by downloading deb file from [here](https://www.pling.com/p/1136805/startdownload?file_id=1530774600&file_name=ocs-url_3.1.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb&file_type=application/x-debian-package&file_size=54502) and then open terminal and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i ocs-url_3.1.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Now when you click `xdg-open`, a window will appear asking for confirmation.

[image]

But if you prefer Pling, you can download the AppImage from [here](https://www.pling.com/p/1175480/startdownload?file_id=1573507674&file_name=pling-store-5.0.2-1-x86_64.AppImage&file_type=application/x-executable&file_size=104824872). Then open terminal and grant execute permissions using

```
chmod +x pling-store-5.0.2-1-x86_64.AppImage
```

And then double click on the app to launch the store.

> **Note:** It seems you have Ubuntu installed which uses GNOME. But here you are trying to install a KDE theme. This might not yield any result. If you really want that theme, I'd suggest you to either install Kubuntu or Kubuntu's desktop environment which is basically based on KDE.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, even a nerd like me can understand clearly.

Comment: @PravalPratap If that helped, you can click on ✓ to mark the answer as accepted.